# Can a levitated object be pushed?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement

Levitate says:

> The target can move only by pushing or pulling against a fixed object or surface within reach.

Does this mean that a levitated object (which cannot push or pull itself) is fixed in its horizontal position or does the force of a hand count as a fixed object to push against, *à la* Newton's third law?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says "[t]he target can move" - it doesn't say "the target can *be* moved ...".

Anyone can grab and move the target following the rules for grappling if a creature, or carrying and dragging if an object. Or you could shove it - metaphorically and literally.